# Is it a good practice to use List of Enums?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented

I am currently working on a system where there are Users, and each user have one or multiple roles. Is it a good practice to use List of Enum values on User? I can't think of anything better, but this doesn't feel alright.

```
enum Role{
  Admin = 1,
  User = 2,
}

class User{
   ...
   List<Role> Roles {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, i'd be interested to see anyone else's comments to the contrary.

Comment: On the assumption that you, in reality, have more than these two roles, then a list of roles like this seems a good approach.

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea to use lists; use vectors or arrays instead.

Comment: @MatthewRock thats a pretty sweeping generalization. List<T> is quite common in the .NET world.

Comment: @Graham But a true generalization. Lists does not have constant random acces time, and thus searching them(which would be the case here) is longer(with vector you can use binary search, quicksearch, or whatever fast algorithm you want to use).

Comment: @MatthewRock .NET List is an arraylist, which has the same properties for the algorithms you mention.

Comment: @imsoconfused I speak about lists as a data structure; List<T> might as well be a set, list, vector, array, map, etc. If your language solves the problems of lists but insists on calling them lists, then they're fine to use again.

Comment: @MatthewRock yes I understand, just wanted to clear up the language between you and Graham. A more clear term for your data structure might be Linked List, which makes the data locality issue more clear imo.

Comment: @MatthewRock - no, you are talking about LINKED lists, when the question, and everyone else, is talking about generic List interface.

Comment: @DavorŽdralo I thought in C# `List` was the implementation and `IList` was the interface?

Comment: @WChargin - where did you get C# from? As far as i can tell, the question is language agnostic.

Comment: Auto properties are a distinctive feature of C# ( the get; set; syntax). Also the List class naming.

Comment: @Dexie What language is this? because Java and C# enums have differences / features, you may or nay not be able to use.

Comment: @DarcyThomas Well, the question was about overall code design, but I am working with c#.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

*TL;DR: It is usually a bad idea to use a collection of enums as it often leads to a bad design. A collection of enums usually calls for distinct system entities with specific logic.*

It is necessary to distinguish between a few use cases of enum. This list is only of top of my head so there might be more cases...

The examples are all in C#, I guess your language of choice will have similar constructs or it would be possible for you to implement them yourself.

**1. Only single value is valid**

In this case, the values are exclusive, e.g.

```cs
public enum WorkStates
{
    Init,
    Pending,
    Done
}
```

It is invalid to have some work that is both `Pending` and `Done`. Therefore only one of these values is valid. This is a good use-case of enum.

**2. A combination of values is valid**
This case is also called flags, C# provides `[Flags]` enum attribute to working with these. The idea can be modeled as a set of `bool`s or `bit`s with each corresponding to one enum member. Each member should have a value of power of two. Combinations can be created using bitwise operators:

```cs
[Flags]
public enum Flags
{
    None = 0,
    Flag0 = 1, // 0x01, 1 << 0
    Flag1 = 2, // 0x02, 1 << 1
    Flag2 = 4, // 0x04, 1 << 2
    Flag3 = 8, // 0x08, 1 << 3
    Flag4 = 16, // 0x10, 1 << 4

    AFrequentlyUsedMask = Flag1 | Flag2 | Flag4,
    All = ~0 // bitwise negation of zero is all ones
}
```

Using a collection of enum members is an overkill in such a case as each enum member only represents one bit that is either set or unset. I guess most of languages support constructs like this. Otherwise you can create one (e.g. use `bool[]` and address it by `(1 << (int)YourEnum.SomeMember) - 1`).

**a) All combinations are valid**

While these are ok in some simple cases, a collection of objects may be more appropriate as you often need additional information or behaviour based on the type.

```cs
[Flags]
public enum Flavors
{
    Strawberry = 1,
    Vanilla = 2,
    Chocolate = 4
}

public class IceCream
{
    private Flavors _scoopFlavors;

    public IceCream(Flavors scoopFlavors)
    {
        _scoopFlavors = scoopFlavors
    }

    public bool HasFlavor(Flavors flavor)
    {
        return _scoopFlavors.HasFlag(flavor);
    }
}
```

(note: this assumes you only really care about the flavors of the ice-cream - that you don't need to model the ice-cream as a collection of scoops and a cone)

**b) Some combinations of values are valid and some not**

This is a frequent scenario. The case might often be that you're putting two different things into one enum. Example:

```cs
[Flags]
public enum Parts
{
    Wheel = 1,
    Window = 2,
    Door = 4,
}

public class Building
{
    public Parts parts { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public Parts parts { get; set; }
}
```

Now while it's completely valid for both `Vehicle` and `Building` to have `Door`s and `Window`s, it's not very usual for `Building`s to have `Wheel`s.

In this case, it would be better to break up the enum into parts and/or modify the object hierarchy in order to achieve either case #1 or #2a).

**Design considerations**

Somehow, the enums tend not to be the driving elements in OO since the type of an entity can be considered similar to the information that is usually provided by an enum.

Take e.g. the `IceCream` sample from #2, the `IceCream` entity would instead of flags have a collection of `Scoop` objects.

The less purist approach would be for the `Scoop` to have a `Flavor` property. The purist approach would be for the `Scoop` to be an abstract base class for `VanillaScoop`, `ChocolateScoop`, ... classes instead.

The bottom line is that:
1. Not everything that is a "type of something" needs to be enum
2. When some enum member is not a valid flag in some scenario, consider splitting the enum into multiple distinct enums.

Now for your example (slightly changed):

```cs
public enum Role
{
    User,
    Admin
}

public class User
{
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

I think this exact case should be modeled as (note: not really extensible!):

```cs
public class User
{
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

In other words - it is implicit, that the `User` is a `User`, the additional info is whether he is an `Admin`.

If you get to have multiple roles that are not exclusive (e.g. `User` can be `Admin`, `Moderator`, `VIP`, ... at the same time), that would be a good time to use either flags enum or an abtract base class or interface.

Using a class to represent a `Role` leads to a better separation of responsibilities where a `Role` can have the responsibility to decide whether it can do a given action.

With an enum you'd need to have the logic in one place for all the roles. Which defeats the purpose of OO and brings you back to imperative.

Imagine that a `Moderator` has edit rights and `Admin` has both edit and delete rights.

Enum approach (called `Permissions` in order not to mix roles and permissions):

```cs
[Flags]
public enum Permissions
{
    None = 0
    CanEdit = 1,
    CanDelete = 2,

    ModeratorPermissions = CanEdit,
    AdminPermissions = ModeratorPermissions | CanDelete
}

public class User
{
    private Permissions _permissions;

    public bool CanExecute(IAction action)
    {
        if (action.Type == ActionType.Edit && _permissions.HasFlag(Permissions.CanEdit))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (action.Type == ActionType.Delete && _permissions.HasFlag(Permissions.CanDelete))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Class approach (this is far from perfect, ideally, you'd want the `IAction` in a visitor pattern but this post is enormous already...):

```cs
public interface IRole
{
    bool CanExecute(IAction action);
}

public class ModeratorRole : IRole
{
    public virtual bool CanExecute(IAction action)
    {
         return action.Type == ActionType.Edit;
    }
}

public class AdminRole : ModeratorRole
{
     public override bool CanExecute(IAction action)
     {
         return base.CanExecute(action) || action.Type == ActionType.Delete;
     }
}

public class User
{
    private List<IRole> _roles;

    public bool CanExecute(IAction action)
    {
        _roles.Any(x => x.CanExecute(action));
    }
}
```

Using an enum may be an acceptable approach though (e.g. performance). The decision here depends on the requirements of the modeled system.

Comment: I don't think that `[Flags]` implies all combinations are valid any more than an int implies all four billion values of that type are valid. It simply means they _can_ be combined within a single field - any restrictions on combinations belongs to higher-level logic.

Comment: Warning: when using `[Flags]`, you should set the values to powers of two, or else it won't work as expected.

Comment: @Random832 I never had an intent of saying that but I edited the answer - hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez Thank you for the input, I have fixed the answer and also added an explanatory note about that.

Comment: Great explanation! Actually flags fit system requirements very-well, however it will be easier to use HashSets due to existing service implementation.

Answer (score 78):

Why not to use Set? If using List:

1. It is easy to add the same role twice
2. Naive compare of lists won't work here properly: [User, Admin] is not the same as [Admin, User]
3. Complex operations such as intersect and merge are not straightforward to implement

If you are concerned about performance, then, for example in Java, there is [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) which is implemented as fixed length array of booleans (i'th boolean element answers the question whether i'th Enum value is present in this set or not). For example, `EnumSet<Role>`. Also, see [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html). I suspect that C# has something similar.

Comment: Actually in Java `EnumSet`s are implemented as bit fields.

Comment: Related SO question on `HashSet<MyEnum>` vs. flags enums: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9077487/87698

Comment: .NET has `FlagsAttribute`, which lets you use bitwise operators to concat enums.  Sounds similar to the Java `EnumSet`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/LIBRARY/system.flagsattribute EDIT: I should've looked down one answer!  it has a good example of this.

Answer (score 4):

Write your enum so you can combine them. By using base 2 exponential you can combine them all in one enum, have 1 property and can check for them. Your enum should be lile this

```
enum MyEnum
{ 
    FIRST_CHOICE = 2,
    SECOND_CHOICE = 4,
    THIRD_CHOICE = 8
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using 1?

Comment: @RobbieDee no effectivly I could have used 1, 2, 4, 8, etc. you're right

Comment: Well, if you use Java, it already has `EnumSet` which implements this for `enum`s. You have all the boolean arithmetic already abstracted, plus some other methods to make it easier to use, plus small memory and good performance.

Comment: @fr13d I'm a c# guy and since the question has no java tag I think this answer apply more at large

Comment: Right, @Rémi. C# provides the `[flags]` attribute, which @Zdeněk Jelínek explores in [his post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/307964/212087).

Answer (score 4):

> Is it a good practice to use List of Enum values on User?

---

**Short answer**: Yes

---

**Better short answer**: Yes, the enum defines something in the domain.

---

**Design-time answer**: Make and use classes, structures, etc. that model the domain in terms of the domain itself.

---

**Coding time answer**: Here's how to code-sling enums ...

---

**The inferred questions**:

- Should I use strings?

  - answer: No.
- Should I use some other class?

  - In addition to, yes. Instead of, no.
- Is the `Role` enum list sufficient for use in `User`?

  - I have no idea. It is highly dependent on other design details not in evidence.

---

**WTF Bob?**

- This is a design question that is framed in programming language technicalities.

  - An `enum` is a good way to define "Roles" in your model. So then a `List` of roles is a good thing.
- `enum` is far superior to strings.

  - `Role` *is a declaration of ALL roles that exist in the domain.*
  - The string "Admin" is a string with the letters `"A"` `"d"` `"m"` `"i"` `"n"`, in that order. It is *nothing* as far as the domain is concerned.
- Any classes you might design to give the concept of `Role` some life - functionality - can make good use of the `Role` enum.

  - For example rather than sub-class for every kind of role, have a `Role` property that tells what kind of role this class-instance is.
  - A `User.Roles` list is reasonable when we don't need, or don't want, instantiated role objects.
  - And when we do need to instantiate a role, the enum is an un-ambiguous, type safe way to communicate that to a `RoleFactory` class; and, not insignificantly, to the code reader.

Answer (score 3):

That isn't something I've seen but I see no reason why it wouldn't work. You might want to use sorted list so it defends against dupes however.

A more common approach is a single user level e.g. system, admin, power user, user etc. System can do everything, admin most things and so on down.

If you were to set the values of roles as powers of two, you could store the role as an int and derive the roles if you really wanted to store them in a single field but that might not be to everyone's taste.

So you might have:

```
Back office role 1
Front office role 2
Warehouse role 4
Systems role 8
```

So if a user had a role value of 6 then they'd have the Front office and Warehouse roles.

Answer (score 2):

Use [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) as it prevents duplicates and has more comparison methods

Otherwise good use of Enum

Add a method Boolean IsInRole(Role R)

and I would skip the set

```
List<Role> roles = new List<Role>();
Public List<Role> Roles { get {return roles;} }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplistic example you give is fine, but typically it's more complicated than that. For instance, if you are going to persist the users and roles in a database, then you should define the roles in a database table rather than use enums. That gives you referential integrity.

Answer (score 0):

If a system — might it be a software, an operation system or an organization — deals with roles and permission, there comes a time when it is useful to add roles and manage permissions for them.
If this can be archived by altering the source code, it might be ok, to stick with enums. But at some point the system's user wants to be able to manage roles and permissions. Than enums become unusable.
Instead you will want to have a configurable data structure. i.e. a UserRole class that also holds a set of permission assigned to the role.
A User class would have a set of roles. If there is the need to check user's permission, a union set of all roles permissions is created and checked if it contains the permission in question.